# I would like to know how I can create a jar file with multiple packages

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have read about a 100 pages on packaging java projects into jar files, spend two day trying all different kind of classpath combinations but have not been able to find the solution to this problem

I have two packages with each a source file.

```java
package frontend.timer;

import backend.Activity;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        Activity myAct = new Activity();
        System.out.println(myAct.greeting());
    }
}
```

and....

```java
package backend;

public class Activity {

    public String greeting() {

        return "Goodby";

    }
}
```

when I compile and run the the project:

```
dir /s /B *.java >sources.txt
javac -d outDir @sources.txt
java -classpath outDir  frontend.timer.Main
```

it runs fine.

Then I created a manifest file:

```
Main-Class: frontend.timer.Main
Class-Path: outDir/
<blanc line here>
```

and compressed and run it with a jar file:

```
jar.exe cfm timer.jar manifest.mf outDir\frontend\timer outDir\backend
java -jar timer.jar
```

it runs fine again.

for clarification the content of the jar file is:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
outDir/frontend/timer/
outDir/frontend/timer/Main.class
outDir/backend/
outDir/backend/Activity.class
```

Now when I copy the jar to another folder it doesn't run:

```
mkdir newDir 
copy timer.jar newDir 
java -jar newDir\timer.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class frontend.timer.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: frontend.timer.Main
```

Simply copying the content of the outDir to the newDir solves it. But that doesn't make sense to me.
Creating two jar files (one for the frontend and one for the backend) results in exact the same thing. All works fine till I move it to another directory.

What am I missing, not seeing, was unable to find?

Answer (score 1):

You have built the MANIFEST.MF with a built in `Class-Path: outDir/` which means that that directory is scanned at runtime for your packaged classes. This is why copying outDir to the newDir solves one issue, java is loading the classes from the outDir folder not the jar.

Fix this by DELETING the `Class-Path: outDir/` entry from MANIFEST.MF

The next issue is that you've packaged your classes with extra directory path prefix `outDir/`. The correct layout of the jar should be:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
frontend/timer/
frontend/timer/Main.class
backend/
backend/Activity.class
```

Build an exploded structure of the jar in `outDir` containing `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and the frontend/backend folders, then create the jar in one step:

```
cd outDir
jar cvf ..\timer.jar .
```

This then means that the jar has identical structure `outDir` and how you have been testing with the exploded folder. Hopefully these will then be equivalent:

```
java -classpath outDir    frontend.timer.Main
java -classpath timer.jar frontend.timer.Main
```

I suggest you also rename outDir => outDir.temp before the jar test to verify that the second call runs with the JAR and not the contents of `outDir`.